# Excel: IF function to compare two cells then copy data from a 3rd cell and paste it in a 4th cell

Tags: excel

I did some searching here and Google and can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Partly I'm having difficulty because my search terms needed are so vague that I get lots of noise in my searches.

I'm building a customized tournament bracket for a few tennis tournaments that I'm running this summer. Because the bracket is complicated and refers the losing player on to other tiers in the bracket, I'd like to automate the process in excel as much as possible (in case I'm playing instead of managing the bracket).

I'm trying to devise the simplest solution possible to mark the winning player in a match, pass the name of the winning players name to the cell for the next match, and pass the losing players name to the appropriate draw in another tier of the bracket.

The best solution I've come up with thus far is to manually put the winning players name in the winning cell then use an IF statement to compare the name to the two possible competitors and copy the one who lost to the correct spot.

So in Match 1 I have "Player A" in cell B1 and "Player B" in cell B3. The winning player would be in cell D2 and the losing player goes to K3.

Something like...

IF(D2=B1, copy B3 to K3, copy B1 to K3)

I just can't figure out how the syntax works on this. Or if there's a simpler solution.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Formulas can't perform copying, but they are not helpless either.

In cell **K3** enter:

```
=IF(D2=B1,B3,B1)
```